# Run Firefox in Backend using Selenium webdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, web-scraping, user-agent

I am working on a website scraping project using Selenium in Python. I am wondering if I can start the firefox in the backend or open Firefox in another workspace in Ubuntu ?

Is it also possible to pass the `user-agent` properties though the webdriver() ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PyVirtualDisplay](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay) should let you run it in the background.

There's a short walkthough [here](http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2011/06/python-headless-selenium-webdriver.html).

And yes, you can change the [User Agent](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Changing_the_user_agent).

Comment: Amazing, Haven't tried the User-Agent part as yet. But your suggestion of PyVirtualDisplay is what I was looking for. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Gnome you might want to try [DevilsPie](http://live.gnome.org/DevilsPie) (or gDevilsPie) to control on which workspace Firefox runs:

A simple RAW rule would be:

```
( if 
( begin 
( is ( application_name ) "Firefox" )
) 
( begin 
( set_workspace 3 )
( println "match" )
)
)
```

I use this with Selenium and it works quite well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this. Running Firefox as a background application is not possible then with `ẁebdriver()` ?